# Error when trying to checkout folders from github: Unable to create files

Tags: reactjs

I'm still very new github. When i'm trying to checkout some folders from my github repository to my working directory, I'm facing this issue:

run this command from command prompt 
 `git checkout d88a4fce9 *`

> Error: unable to create file Projects/React/keeper-app-part-1-starting/node_modules/jest-environment-jsdom-fourteen/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/constraint-validation/DefaultConstraintValidation-impl.js: Filename too long 
> Updated 2 paths from 505996af2

### Environment:

Operating System: Windows 10 Pro
node : v14.16.0
npm : 6.14.11

Please advise on what should I do next. Thanks in advance!! ^_^

Comment: Could you share a link to your GitHub repository? At first glance, it seems like you haven't put `node_modules` into `.gitignore`. See [Ignoring files](https://docs.github.com/en/github/using-git/ignoring-files)

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply. Here's my github repository: https://github.com/AbrialWong/WebDevelopmentBootcamp

Comment: I see this is a pretty new/short project. Perhaps you could try creating a new project using [`create-react-app`](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app). That way you can focus on programming instead of dealing with issues like this one.

Comment: Okay noted. Thank you for your help. Have a nice day! :D

Answer (score 0):

Please try creating .gitignore in the base directory of the project and adding node_modules to it.

```
node_modules
```

Comment: yup i did that. Thanks for your help! Have a nice day! :D